# Select for SQLite Database Browser

Tags: database, sqlite

How do I write the Select statement for this? When I only want to get the BOLD data from the database?

*Choose the least water spill for each day.

Id Date WaterSpill

1   10/10/2011  70

**2 10/10/2011  30**

3   10/10/2011  50

**4 11/10/2011  20**

5   11/10/2011  60

**6 12/10/2011  40**

7   12/10/2011  80

Comment: This question is **useless** as presented.  What are the structures of the tables that you want to query?

Comment: Jack Maney has a good point here. While the data given lets us pretty much guess that you have `id` `date` `spills` in a table, it would really help if you posted the actual structure for clarification, as well as the queries you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table is named **spills**, this should give you your results:

```
SELECT id, date, MIN(waterspill) AS waterspill FROM spills s 
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date
```